# Formatos de Primary Key

Tags: sql, lenguaje-agnóstico

Tengo unas dudas que me gustaría aclarar, he tenido jefes que nunca han querido trabajar con ID Identity que lo crea el mismo gestor de base de datos, por la siguiente razón que se pierde el correlativo.
En mi opinion el ID no se muestra al cliente para que preocuparme en mostrarlo o no puede ir oculto.

Hay desarrolladores que prefieren crear su propio ID dandole el tamaño del campo como 0001, 000001, etc

¿Cual de las dos maneras es un buena práctica de programación?
¿Crear sus propios ID de tipo string con el tamaño que uno desee, es de la época de los dinosaurios?

Comment: Actualmente el id no es parte de la entidad, es un elemento agregado para mantener las relaciones, por ello no importa su valor mientras que las entidades relacionadas mantengan el mismo valor. Pero... Tus jefes, quizá usaban computadores con cinta, estas máquinas requerían cierta correlatividad pues el id se usaba para calcular la posición del registro en cinta. Así que es una técnica obsoleta, pero no tiene 65 millones de años ;) Quizá unos 50

Comment: Hola, entonces vas por identiry?

Comment: Si, no tiene que ser importante el id. aprovecho para decir que este tipo de preguntas no son apropiadas aquí...  Pero en el chat puede ser

Comment: @rnd en realidad me parece que es una pregunta válida para el sitio. Pedro consulta si la estrategia de utilizar ID Identity es válida o no, y eso tiene una respuesta objetiva con puntos a favor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Desde mi punto de vista es importante utilizar los IDs que se auto-generan por los siguientes motivos:

**1. A Favor**

- **Ocupan poco espacio**: Los IDs ocupan poco espacio (y mucho menos que los que comentas de `001`, `0001` o `00000001`) ya que son auto-incrementales en ese sentido y numéricos).
- **Permiten separar la lógica**: Si se utiliza otro tipo de campo que no sea el ID como Primary Key y se necesita hacer un cambio debido a la lógica, tenemos un problema. Utilizar los ID por defecto te permite despreocuparte de la lógica que peuda tener y sus posibles cambios.
- **Permiten la rápida utilización de joins y otras consultas** - Si todas las tablas tienen un ID y se quiere hacer una join; hacer una FK que se mantenga con los IDs para todas las tablas te permite programar siempre de la misma manera, sin tener que consultar en cada momento cómo se llama el campo o si realmente se puede hacer.
- **Índices**: algo MUY importante. Realizar índices sobre IDs es fácil y rápido. Su utilización es igual de fácil y no dependen de otros datos por lo que su acceso es rapidísimo.

**2. En contra** - No todo es bueno

- **No evitan duplicados ni su control**: si una tabla tiene un ID creado a partir de, por ejemplo, un DNI/Nombre+Apellido/etc... puedes mantener fácilmente un control de duplicados; eso no es así en este caso y se tiene que realizar con lógica de cliente/servidor/SQL-triggers-something de alguna otra manera. **Aunque** es posible utilizar columnas `unique` para solventar este problema pueden afectar al rendimiento de las tablas.

Seguramente hay otros motivos pero desde mi punto de vista es importante utilizarlos, ya que las ventajas que ofrece utilizar el ID auto-generado para la mayoría de proyectos es lo ideal, las bases de datos SQl ya son por defecto una solución *genérica* en sí, para soluciones *especializadas* existen bases de datos **NOSQL**. En casos muy concretos no tiene por qué ser así, pero la norma general es esa.

Comment: Mi opinión es también usar los ID's autogenerados. Me parece que es mucho mas eficiente. Comparto la misma idea de esta respuesta.

Comment: No entiendo la observación "en contra" sobre duplicados. Para garantizar unicidad sobre otras columnas (serían algo así como claves secundarias),  es tan simple como agregar un indice con restriccion "UNIQUE" sobre esas columnas y listo.

Comment: Poner UNIQUE múltiple afecta a el rendimiento de manera importante.

Answer (score -1):

"Perder la correlatividad" (supongo que se refiere a que pueden aparecer "agujeros" en la secuencia) no es ningún problema. Una clave primaria "artificial" no debería tener ningún impacto en la lógica de negocios.

Pretender tener una clave primaria incremental consecutiva (sin agujeros) implicaría una lógica bastante complicada para evitar "race conditions" (sesiones concurrentes que quieren agregar un registro simultáneamente). No tiene sentido - hablando en general.

> ¿Crear sus propios ID de tipo string con el tamaño que uno desee, es de la época de los dinosaurios?

No necesariamente, pero sí probablemente. (Tampoco entiendo muy bien qué tiene que ver usar un string de ancho fijo con el hecho de mantener correlatividad) Por otro lado, a menos que realmente sepan lo que están haciendo (quién controla la secuencia? qué ocurre si dos sesiones concurrentes intentan insertar un registro nuevo?), la generación es proclive a errores y problemas de mantenimiento.

Comment: No sé exactamente porque te han dado negativos pero quiero creer que es porque no aclaras explícitamente cual es tu posición, aunque claro, si lees todo se puede deducir. +1 por race conditions con compromiso a expresar tus ideas de manera más ordenada :).